# Is it possible to let a superclass to have all subclass as a class variable

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming, class-variables

Is it possible to let a superclass to have all subclass's type (`Type`) as a class variable (`ClassVar`)?

For example, if we have

```py
class A:
    sub_types: ClassVar[List[Type["A"]]]

class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(A): pass
```

What I want is `A.sub_types = [A, B, C, D]` and `B.sub_type = [A, B, C, D]` and the same for both `C` and `D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we may leverage [`__init_subclass_`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) for this behavior and then have a list modified for each subclass. Like this :

```py
class SubTypeWatch:
    sub_types = []

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs) -> None:
        cls.sub_types.append(cls)
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
```

Then let your first child (root) class Inherit this

```py
class A(SubTypeWatch):
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C(B):
    pass


class D(C):
    pass
```

This would result in a shared common `sub_type` between children.

And it's the same for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as you specified (it's the same `list` instance even).

```py
>>> A.sub_types
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>]
>>> B.sub_types 
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>]
>>> C.sub_types 
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>]
>>> D.sub_types 
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>]
>>>
```